# Reduce but not increase background size

Tags: image, css, background-image

```
background: #344b68 url(../../data/img/template/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover;    
-o-background-size: cover;      
background-size: cover;
```

Hello once again Stackoverflow, I have the following question.

Background.jpg is my websites background picture, wich is in `1080p` resolution (1920x1080). On the border of the image, it fades to `#344b68`.

Viewing this on a `720p` monitor will cause the picture to reduce in size using `background-size: cover`but this will also be increased when viewing this on for example `1440p` resolutions.

Now what I want to do is when it's a `720p` monitor reduce the image' dimensions with `background-size: cover` to fit, but when its above `1080p`, it stays the same dimentions and just fades in with the static background color (`#344b68`).

How can I do this, preferibly without JS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)! These are a CSS3 feature that let you specify code to only activate when certain conditions are met. In your case, you want to query the window width:

```
/* normal styles */
.item-with-background {
    background-size: contain;
}

/* overrides when screen is 720px wide or smaller */
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .item-with-background {
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Note: Media queries are supported in basically all the browsers (including mobile) except IE 6/7/8. If you REALLY need to have media queries in use in those browsers, [there are some polyfills that hack-in that ability.](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Comment: nice solution. and the main class can contain the background color. pretty neat.